# Php array conversion

Tags: php, arrays

**Edit**: I just figured out that my situation was a bit more complex. I edited the question consequently.

I have an array in this format:

```
[
    [
        "key" => "key1",
        "field1" => "a1",
        "field2" => "b1"
    ],
    [
        "key" => "key2",
        "field1" => "a2",
        "field2" => "b2"
    ]
]
```

I want to define a function to convert it into this:

```
[
    "key1" => [
        "field1" => "a1",
        "field2" => "b1"
    ],
    "key2" => [
        "field1" => "a2",
        "field2" => "b2"
    ]
]
```

And another function to reverse the process.

I managed to write the first function

```
function ($array, $key) {
    return array_reduce($array, function ($carry, $item) use ($key) {
        $new = array_diff_key($item, [$key=>0]);
        $carry[$item[$key]] = $new;
        return $carry;
    }, []);
}
```

but now i'm having trouble with the reverse.

PS: **I'm trying to avoid for loops**

Any idea?

Comment: You can not avoid them here. Try using them.

Answer (score 2):

PHP >= 5.5 has a built-in function called [array_column()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to do this for you:

```
$array = array_column($array, 'value', 'key');
```

Comment: I just figured out that my situation was a bit more complex. I edited the question consequently. Sorry for the inconvenience.